# How Do I Run a Subset of Unit Tests Gulp-Angular with Karma?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm working on an AngularJS 1.4 project that was created from the Gulp-Angular yeoman generator. It has karma and gulp already configured so that when I run ***gulp test*** from the command line karma runs all of my *.spec.js files. My problem is that it always run ALL of my spec.js files in the entire project. I would like to just run one or two spec.js files- even better to be able to specify a folder and have it find all spec.js files recursively.

- I've tried just cd'ing down to a folder, but it still runs all tests.
- I've also tried editing this line in karma.conf.js:
  path.join(conf.paths.src, '/**/*.spec.js'),
- and this line in the gulp directory's unit-tests.js file:
  path.join(conf.paths.src, '/**/!(*.spec).js')

However, when I edit them I still get all the test suites in the whole entire project running! Ahh!

There must be a way to do what I'm trying to do. Can anyone help me out with the correct approach here?

Comment: Current answer doesn't work. Does anyone else have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Karma is the test runner. Yeoman's [gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) generator uses Jasmine as the tester.

Search for a file jasmine.json.

There is a `"spec_dir"` and a `"spec_files"` section that looks something like:

```
  "spec_dir": "./",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.js"
  ],
```

Modify it to fit your needs. I'm guessing something along the line:

```
  "spec_dir": "./some_specific_path",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.js"
  ],
```

or if you want to do it incrementally from the root:

```
  "spec_dir": "./",
  "spec_files": [
    "some_specific_path_1/**/*[sS]pec.js",
    "some_specific_path_2/**/*[sS]pec.js"
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see a jasmine.json file anywhere in the project. There's only jasmine.js in gulp-protractor | protractor | node_modules | jasmine | bin, but I don't think that's it. :/

Comment: ok, then try protractor.conf.json. Change the specs section. The above path styles apply.

Comment: Can you please put full paths. There is no protractor.conf.json in my project.

Comment: Change what? In protractor.conf.js I tried changing this:  specs: [paths.e2e + '/**/*.js'], but nothing happens. There are no spec_dir or spec_files objects in protractor.spec.js.

Comment: I tried changing src in export.paths in conf.js in the gulp folder: exports.paths = {
  src: 'src',
  dist: 'dist',
  tmp: '.tmp',
  e2e: 'e2e'
}; However, I can't seem to use an array of paths for src here.